# How to create a table in a form in Visual Studio

Tags: forms, visual-studio

How can I make a table, like an excel table, to show the contents of a two dimensional dynamic array in visual studio?

I see that in visual studio 2008 there was a table object to be added to a form, but I can't seem to find anything similar in 2013. Datagridview seems to do the job but it involves creating a SQL database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataGridView` is the solution. You don't need a SQL database. Just fill a `DataTable` with your data (row by row) and set the data source of the `DataGridView` as this `DataTable`.

```
 // Create and populate the datatable
 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
 DataColumn[] columns = {new DataColumn("ID"), new DataColumn("Value")};
 Object[] row1 = {"1", "Value1"};
 Object[] row2 = {"2", "Value2"};
 Object[] row3 = {"3", "Value3"};
 dataTable.Columns.AddRange(columns);
 dataTable.Rows.Add(row1);
 dataTable.Rows.Add(row2);
 dataTable.Rows.Add(row3);

 //Set the data source
 dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because datagrid is supposed to work with database.
Anyway I guess you're looking to integrate an excel table inside your form, right?
In that case [this should help!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati) 

What have you tried until now?!

Comment: I wanted a more simple table, really datagrid seems to work! Thank you for your time sir.